# PyGTK Z-order doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, z-order

I am working on a chat GUI, and I'm trying to put a send button on top of the TextView.  I'm using a Table, and I'm attaching both widgets to the same place.  The positioning of the widgets is determined by the Alignment containers that I'm putting them both in.  The problem is that the TextView covers up the image (I'll make it respond to clicks later).  I tried making the image's alignment rise in the Z-order by using `align2.window.raise_()`, but that didn't change anything.  I also tried doing all of the `.show()`'s manually to make sure that the image's came last, but that didn't work either.

How can I keep the TextView from covering up the image while still letting it take up all the room it can get?

Here is my basic code:

```
align1 = gtk.Alignment(0, 0, 1, 1)
align2 = gtk.Alignment(1)

table = gtk.Table()
window.add(table)
table.attach(align1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
table.attach(align2, 0, 1, 0, 1)

textview = gtk.TextView()
align1.add(textview)
im = gtk.image_new_from_file("/home/commandant/Desktop/send.png")
align2.add(im)

window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Use GtkOverlay.

Comment: Note that using GtkOverlay means moving to Gtk3 which is probably good in general as pygtk is dead and unsupported.